# How to fix 'strided slice assignment are not compatible with expected types' in Tensorflow 1.14.0rc in autograph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, variable-assignment

I'm trying to implement the Sliding DFT algorithm in tensorflow 1.14.0 and am using tf.function so that I dont have to worry to much about control flow, however I am running into a problem. When I attempt to assign an element of a variable with another element in that variable, I get an error in regards to incompatible types in strided slice assignments.

I've tried using tf.scatter update, tf assign, and using just a typical slice assign, however none of these have worked.

```
    @tf.function
    def sdft_func(self,input_tensor):
        for i in range(self.N_t):
        #retrieving variables so that I have direct access to it
        #instead of getting access to the read tensor
        _, _, self.in_s = self.get_variables()
        last = self.in_s[self.N_t-1]
        for j in range(self.N_t,0,-1):
            _, _, self.in_s = self.get_variables()
            val = self.in_s[j-1]
            #The line below gives the error
            self.in_s = self.in_s[j].assign(val)
            print(self.in_s)
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

> TypeError: In op 'strided_slice_1/_assign', input types ([tf.complex64, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.complex64]) are not compatible with expected types ([tf.complex64_ref, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.complex64])

Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I narrowed down the problem as having to do with attempting to set tf.complex64 variables inside of tf.function functions. So in order to overcome this, I simply abstracted away the operation so that the variable setting was done outside of the tf.function function. See below for the solution:

```py
    def sdft_func(self,input_tensor):

        @tf.function
        def func(input_tensor,N_t,in_s,coeffs,freqs):
            in_s = tf.identity(in_s)
            coeffs = tf.identity(coeffs)
            freqs = tf.identity(freqs)


            for i in range(N_t):
                last = in_s[self.N_t-1]

                in_s = in_s[:-1]
                new_val = tf.expand_dims(tf.complex(input_tensor[i],
                                tf.cast(0.0,dtype=tf.float32)),0)

                in_s = tf.concat([new_val,in_s],axis=0)
                    delta = in_s[0] - last

                freqs_2 = tf.TensorArray(tf.complex64,size=self.N)

                for j in range(self.N_t):
                    freqs_2 = freqs_2.write(j,(freqs[j]+delta)*coeffs[j])
                freqs = freqs_2.stack()
                freqs.set_shape([self.N])

            return freqs,in_s

        new_freqs, new_in_s = func(input_tensor,self.N_t,
                self.in_s,self.coeffs,self.freqs)

        self.in_s = self.in_s.assign(new_in_s)
        self.freqs = self.freqs.assign(new_freqs)
```